# angular 2,node js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular

I have created an Angular-cli CRUD project with validations [project link here](https://github.com/sunilbhatraju/AngularCRUD1) . Now I am trying to store those input form details in MongoDB. Although I found some tutorials/sample codes doing this kind of applications, the organization of the code/project is different form each other. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way so far to do that.

Basically,

- what is the best approach to creating this project with NodeJs back end?
- what should be the folder structure?
- where to put the database code with REST API's?
- how can I view my submitted data in my Mongodb once it is stored?

Kindly please provide the neccessary good tutorials and links if there are any available.

I found many of them in AngularJS(1st Version) but not in 2nd or 4th versions

Comment: Refer this link it's a simple backend structure  https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

Comment: the project structure is different to mine.. I have used angular cli with app components but the link provided by you is different.. i am newbie to angular and MEAN stack.. if there are any good links related to my query plz do provide.. i have been checking for dem since these past 4days

Comment: Can anyone do provide an answer for me by checking my project structure and tell what are the files that are required for me to store my three inputs in the mongodb.. thank you